# Why is my query slow for select smaller than, greater than in combination with an index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
WHERE longitude > 5.71873540775 
  AND longitude < 6.30763059225 
  AND latitude > 52.1688986788 
  AND latitude < 52.5286273212 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This query is running very slow. I tried both a combined index and separate index on longitude and latitude.  The table contains many rows(200.000), and 10 columns. The number of results for the above query is 20.

How could I make this particular query run faster?

UPDATE 1

This is the execution plan:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table_1     range   longitude,latitude  longitude   6   NULL    1401    Using where
```

Comment: Please post MySQL's execution plan for your query, by using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html).

Comment: how many rows do you have in your table? What columns do you have in your table and waht columns do you need in the result?

Comment: @eggyal I added the results of explain in the question

Comment: @RomanPekar I updated the question, for the result I need details from all 10 columns.

Comment: please post `DESCRIBE table_1`

Comment: You should use a spatial datatype and index (that requires a MyISAM table unfortunately in MySQL, up to now. Hopefully we'll have spatial indexes in InnoDB in future versions). Check this answer why a 2-range query cannot effectively use simple b-tree indexes: **[How does R-Tree outperform B-Tree for simple check if a point is within a rectangle](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19640/how-does-r-tree-outperform-b-tree-for-simple-check-if-a-point-is-within-a-rectan/19647#19647)**

Comment: MySQL docs: **[Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html)** and **[Creating Spatial Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html)**

Comment: How slow is this query?  What are the types/sizes of the other fields in the table?   I created a random dataset that fits within the lat/long ranges using both decimal and float types and couldn't a query to take longer than .1 s.  That is both with and without indexing.

Answer (score 0):

As ypercube says, 2 range queries don't work well. But maybe you can't switch your engine to myISAM for whatever reason. We can do this by subdividing out work into two queries that range  lookup separately.

You should need seperate indexes one on the latitude field, one on longitude.

```
SELECT * FROM

(
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE longitude > 5.71873540775 
  AND longitude < 6.30763059225 
) a,
(
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE latitude > 52.1688986788 
  AND latitude < 52.5286273212 
) b

WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Still won't be as fast as using spatial indexes, but might be a bit faster than your current method.